# Posts show up under "published" but not "all"

Tags: custom-post-types, query

I'm having a problem where a custom post type is no longer showing up under "all" within the post admin area. The posts still exist and as you can see from the picture attached, are labeled as **published** but they don't show up in the list. This seems to be effecting a query somewhere because the posts are no longer visible on an archive like page on the front end.

[image: Posts showing up as published, but not as all]

I'm not quite sure what could be causing this. This seems to be the only post type that this is happening for. Any help or direction to look would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It is impossible/very difficult to help you. There are alot of possible reasons, any plugin affecting your post type could be responsible for this ..

Comment: It will be pain, but you can deactivate plugins one by one to detect what causes problem. You can also switch to default theme to check if you theme has issues